# Inno Setup Use a part of an application path for an icon path

Tags: installation, inno-setup, pascalscript

I need to insert the last part of the installation dirrectory in the icon name.

To do that I'm trying to use `ExtractFileName({app})`, and insert its result in the `Name` parameter of my icon.

```
[Icons]
Name: '{group}\ApplicationName\' + ExtractFileName({app}) + '\filename.txt'
```

It compiles, but at runtime I get a 123 error, telling that

> c:\Windows\system32\'c: could not be created.

I just need to insert the basename of the installation path as a new level in start menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a [scripted constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptconstants).

```pascal
[Icons]
Name: "{group}\ApplicationName\{code:GetAppName}\filename.txt"

[Code]

function GetAppName(Param: string): string;
begin
  Result := ExtractFileName(ExpandConstant('{app}'));
end;
```